# How to remove all event handlers for child elements of a parent element using JQuery

Tags: jquery

Given a specific parent node, for example a dynamically created modal div. After adding a bunch of dynamic html to it and then binding those elements to click, mouseover, etc events, is there a way to un-bind all of the events associated with child elements of the modal div. In my specific example, once the modal div is hidden it is then removed from the dom entirely and then recreated from scratch each time it is needed.

I am looking for a way to not have to track all of the specific bindings, but rather just use one call to say: get any children elements that have bindings and 'off' them.

Note: I can validate that removing the element from the dom and then recreating it does not kill the binding as opening and closing the modal div causes the bound events to be fired the same number of times the div was created. I am using `$(document).on('click', '#abc',function(e) {});` to bind elements.

Comment: Show how (or an example of how) you're binding. But I'd suggest [`off()`](http://api.jquery.com/off/), if you're using [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/off/),

Comment: Interesting. Reading the docs I noticed, _To remove all delegated events from an element without removing non-delegated events, use the special value "**"._ Didn't know that.

Comment: how to do this in plain javascript?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use [unbind()](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) if you used `bind()` to attach the events.

```
  $('#foo').children().unbind();
  $('#foo').children('.class').unbind(); //You can give selector for limiting clildren
```

or

Use [off()](http://api.jquery.com/off/) if you used `on()` to bind events.

```
 $('#foo').children().off();
 $('#foo').children('class').off();   //You can give selector for limiting clildren
```

For removing the event from all descendants instead of direct children you can use [Descendant Selector (“ancestor descendant”)](https://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/) .

```
$('#foo *').off();
```

Comment: `children()` only gets direct children though and not all descendants.

Answer (score 21):

Yeap - use `off()` with no params - that will unbind all events bound.

```
$('#parent *').off();
```

If you meant literally children, i.e. not children OR descendants, use `#parent > *` instead.

Answer (score 5):

I also wondered if I needed to manually unbind every children of the removed element.

From jquery documentation you shouldn't:

[jquery docs for remove](http://api.jquery.com/remove/)

> If we had any number of nested elements inside , they would be removed, too. Other jQuery constructs such as data or event handlers are erased as well.

Since I was curious if this was true I checked the source code:

```
function remove( elem, selector, keepData ) {
    var node,
        nodes = selector ? jQuery.filter( selector, elem ) : elem,
        i = 0;

    for ( ; ( node = nodes[ i ] ) != null; i++ ) {
        if ( !keepData && node.nodeType === 1 ) {
            jQuery.cleanData( getAll( node ) );
        }

        if ( node.parentNode ) {
            if ( keepData && jQuery.contains( node.ownerDocument, node ) ) {
                setGlobalEval( getAll( node, "script" ) );
            }
            node.parentNode.removeChild( node );
        }
    }

    return elem;
}
```

as you can see:

```
jQuery.cleanData( getAll( node ) );
```

is cleaning all the events of all the childrens of the removed element.

So in the end: if you use `$(element).remove()` or `.empty()`, you are already memory leak safe!

Answer (score 1):

There are some cases where you don't want to bind an event directly to an element. Rather, you want to bind it to a parent element, like "body" for example. This is essential when you want to define your event listeners globally but the element may not exist yet:

```
$("body").on("mouseenter", ".hover-item", function() {
    // do the thing
}
```

The problem here is if you try to run .off() on ".hover-item" it doesn't work. Alternatively, if you try to use .off() on "body", using .children() as recommended in the accepted answer, it doesn't do anything either.

Instead of using .off(), I believe it's best practice to bind your events to a particular class name, and when you want to disable those events, remove the class name:

```
$(".the-element").removeClass(".hover-item");
```

Now that particular element won't have the event listener enabled anymore. However, since you technically defined the event listener on "body", if you need to enable the hover effect again at some later time, you can just use addClass(".hover-item") and everything will work just fine.

Now, this really only applies in cases where you have one animation for multiple items. Hover events are a good example of this. Instead of applying different hover events to different buttons for example, you can apply the same event to all buttons. But if you just want to disable hover events for one particular button, this is the way to go.