# how do I disable all onClick on a child element of a div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div with an id of `registerModal`. I wanted to disable all 'click' event inside the div's. For example I have the following:

```
<a id="instagram-login-btn" class="inst-btn" href="">

</a>
```

and the following:

```
$('#instagram-login-btn').on('click', function (event) {

});
```

I tried doing:

```
$('#registerModal').off('click', '**');
```

but this didn't work out. Any other way to disable all clicks on a child elements div?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove all event handlers for child elements of a parent element using JQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12012882/how-to-remove-all-event-handlers-for-child-elements-of-a-parent-element-using-jq)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use event delegation which is disabled by the presence of a class.

```
var modal = $('#registerModal');

modal.on('click', "#instagram-login-btn:not(.disabled)", function(event) {
    // the handler
});
modal.on("click", "#another_element:not(.disabled)", function(event) {
    // the handler
});
```

Then to disable them, add the `disabled` class.

```
$("#registerModal *").addClass("disabled");
```

And remove the class to enable.

```
$("#registerModal *").removeClass("disabled");
```

These are adding/removing the class on all nested elements, but your actual code can be more targeted.

---

Another way to do it without classes is to bind handlers that stop the propagation of the event to the nested elements.

```
var modal = $('#registerModal');

modal.on('click', "#instagram-login-btn", function(event) {
    // the handler
});
modal.on("click", "#another_element", function(event) {
    // the handler
});
```

Then to disable them, stop the bubbling with a handler

```
$("#registerModal *").on("click", function(event) { event.stopPropagation() });
```

And remove the handler to enable.

```
$("#registerModal *").off("click");
```

Again, the selection should be targeted toward the actual desired elements.

Comment: I also would like to mention that I do like this idea. We use delegation a lot in our handlers.  So, clean way, because for this case, you can also use the class change with something like class toggle, then have a call back to bind and so on.....

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('#registerModal').find('*').addBack().off('click',);
```

Comment: and how do I turn things back on again?

Comment: @adit In this case you can't turn it on again.... you need to register all the event handlers again

Comment: well..that's not what I want then

Comment: @adit in that case you can't use `.off`, you need to handler the disabled state in each of the click handlers

Answer (score 0):

To set each one, and verify, I always do it in a loop. Such as the following:

```
  $('#registerModal').find("*").each(function(i,e)
  {

      $(this).unbind("click");
  });
```

All answer are pragmatically correct, but I have tend to notice more stable behavior with multiple event handling using the $.each for it.