# Remove all events binding inside a parent div using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have `myclass` div and inside that there are many childs with different event binding. On clicking "remove" below, I want to remove all events binding of all child in it. But following code is not working.

```
<div class="myclass">
  <select class="selectable">
    <option value="1">one</option>
    <option value="2">two</option>
  </select>
  <!-- I have many more elements ~30 or so with events associated with them.... -->
  <div id="askme">ask me</div>

</div>
<div class="xyz">i have event on this element too that should remain intact>/div>
<div id="remove">remove</div>

<script language="javascript">

  $(document).on('ready page:load', function () {

    $(document).on("change",".selectable", function(e) {
      //something
    });

    $(document).on("click","#askme",function(e){
      //something
    });

    //more events binding here.....
  });


  // Using http://api.jquery.com/off/
  $("#remove").on('click', function (e) {
    $(".myclass *").off(); //unbind event of all child under `myclass` parent div
  });

</script>
```

When I click "remove", I want to remove all events associated with all elements inside `myclass` div.

I don't want to use `.one` for invoking events with child elements only once. So that is out of scope to solve this problem.

**Note:**
I have other dom elements in document, that should remain intact. SO I cannot unbind events on document level

Comment: Is this only for events that have been created using jQuery or are you trying to remove other third party events also. Big difference

Comment: @charlietfl created using jquery only

Comment: thx...just wanted to be clear...have seen these types of questions have huge expectations of removing other events also

Comment: what is reason for doing all this? might be other solutions

Comment: I get the piece of html with js via ajax call and append in document. That html has some elements with event associated with them. User can click any element in that new html piece and perform some action. User can later remove newly added html and again add it. Once it get added again, if use clicks the same element again, then it fires event twice.

Comment: Then all this excercise is to fix bad design that can easily be fixed using event delegation. Bind all the events once and be done. You are using event delegation already...`$(document).on("change",".selectable"` ... that code should never be called again and will work for all future elements

Comment: @charlietfl its not easy to conclude about design without knowing the whole detail, so unfortunately, that is not what my question is about. Lets stick to the problem, mentioned here. And FYI, that piece of new html is shared in many pages.

Comment: but the point I'm making is there are easy ways to not bind the events twice....which is what you are trying to fix. That being said if you namespaced them you can add `off()` when you create each one ..`$(document).off('change.selectable').on('change.selectable', '.selectable', func....`

Comment: There is no simple approach ....no matter what you do will take some work to resolve this problem

Comment: @charlietfl can you be little more detailed or have small snippet as what do you mean by namespacing or how code will look like?

Comment: yes...the word after `change.` 2 comments up is `namespace`. It means you could have numerous `change` on element and only remove the one with same name

Comment: http://www.andismith.com/blog/2013/02/jquery-on-and-off-namespacing/

Comment: Thanks @charlietfl for the pointer. I will check it out to see if that can solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

This answer was from a previous post [How to remove all event handlers for child elements of a parent element using JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12012882/how-to-remove-all-event-handlers-for-child-elements-of-a-parent-element-using-jq)

You can use unbind() if you used bind() to attach the events.

```
$('#foo').children().unbind();
$('#foo').children('.class').unbind(); //You can give selector for limiting clildren
```

or

Use off() if you used on() to bind events.

```
$('#foo').children().off();
$('#foo').children('class').off()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have attached the events to the `document`, so you need to do the `off` in `document` element:

```
$(document).off();
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/hk2zv7fd/)

**EDIT:**

Then you need to unbind this way:

```
$("#remove").on('click', function (e) {
    $(document).off("click","#askme");
    $(document).off("change",".selectable");
});
```

[**DEMO2**](https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/hk2zv7fd/2/)

Comment: No, I have other dom elements in document, that should remain intact

Comment: also using event namespaces can be helpful for situations like this

Comment: That will be cumbersome, as I have many elements there...see my comment "I have many more elements ~30 or so with events associated with them" and there could be element which are created dynamically as well

Comment: @JVK if you want some left and some not you need a way to target them. You could create some arrays to store event info and then loop over arrays. There are also data stores for all these events. Using a namespacing approach might let you loop through data store and do removals