# How to remove all event handlers for child elements of a parent element using plain Javascript?

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom-events

I need to remove all event handlers on all elements inside a parent div using plain Javascript.

How can this be achieved?

Will removing all child nodes inside the parent div remove the event handlers as well?

Or will the event handlers have to be removed separately?

Here is the jQuery equivalent

[How to remove all event handlers for child elements of a parent element using JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12012882/how-to-remove-all-event-handlers-for-child-elements-of-a-parent-element-using-jq/12012900)

Comment: You cannot remove event handlers from nodes without knowing the handlers in plain JS.

Comment: Will removing all child nodes inside the parent div remove the event handlers as well?

Comment: "*Will removing all child nodes inside the parent div remove the event handlers as well?*" - yes, of course they are removed when they are no longer part of the document - but that requires destroying the nodes as well.

Comment: solves my problem thanks